# java - scanning txt into 2D arrays with own class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

to start with i want to say this is no homework or somthing, i just want deeper knowledge about these kind of arrays with I/O so feel free to just tell me how you tackle the problem WITH SCANNER, if its solvable :P

if i have a txt file that is like:

```
    car 1 2 3 4 5
    boat 1 2 3 4 5
    plane 1 2 3 4 5
```

and i have made a new class in new .java-file which is an abstract 2d array:

```
    class Type
    {
           String type;
           int number;
    }
    public toString()
    {
            return String.format("%02d:%02d", type, number);
    }
```

is it possible to get an outprint like:

```
    car:1 car:2 car:3
    boat:1 boat:2 boat:3
```

etc? thanks.

edit: also an ArrayList of course..

edit2:

```
    while (scanner.hasNext())
    {
        list.add(scanner.hasNext(), 0); //the array should be <car, 0>
    }                                  //later i will loop through numbers
```

Comment: It's solvable. Why not give it a try first before posting here? You won't break your computer by doing this, and even if your code doesn't work, you'll learn much more in the process of trying to push your abilities than you would if someone spoon-feeds you a solution.

Comment: i have tried, but unfortunately i have so much other to study like maths so i dont have too much time to experiment >.<

Comment: You state: `i have tried, but unfortunately i have so much other to study like maths so i dont have too much time to experiment` -- So in effect you're saying that your time is more valuable than ours? Come on now!

Comment: i get stuck on this part also:
ArrayList<Type> list = new ArrayList<Type>();
....
list.add(scanner.nextInt(), null); //adding the type

and i just dont seem to know how to iterate and put the number, can you use indices with scanner like scanner.nextInt(1) (which would be first number)

Comment: im only meaning what im saying, that lack of time prevents me from experimenting. but alright, ill check into it in some weeks when im done with my exams then... close this :)
edit: you are mean, hovercraft :(

Comment: To solve this with a Scanner, consider using two Scanners, one to read each line, and the other that you create inside of your `while (firstScanner.hasNextLine())` loop to read each token contained in the line. Again, experiment with it and you'll probably get it to work. If you go this route though, don't forget to dispose of each Scanner object when you're done with it.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use 1 Scanner to read each line, and then split the String that you get via `myString.split(" ");` and then iterate through the array returned in a for loop.

Comment: yea im about to do that now. the thing i dont get with abstract arrays (or any of dimension > 1) how you add just one.
i mean if i scan the first token in the line, which is the type i want to "list.add(scanner.next(), <empty here, not adding to number>)" and then loop and add the numbers with the type.

i think the javadocs/tuts lacs the info about these kind of things, or i just havent learned how to search properly

Comment: Please clarify your question including showing the code of just what you mean in the statement above as an edit to your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudo-code of what I'm suggesting is this:

```
create line Scanner
while scanner has next *line*
   get the next line
   use String#split(" ") to create a String array from this line
   Create your object from the items in this array
   Add your new object into your list
end while loop
```

Comment: yeah i guess this is the answer, i did a similar pseudo-sketch when i thought about this problem:

        (while scanner has next line)
        (save the next line first in the array list<Type, Number>)
        (while scanner.hasNextInt(), print <Car, 1> and increment num)

and i still dont understand how to get my 2d arrays to work properly as my edit, so thanks for the post and ill get back at this problem in a couple of weeks when i have more time to learn about 2d-arrays in action with scanners, im not gettin anywhere at this point :P

darnit, codebrackets doesnt work for replies >.<

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is this (assuming your file will always have that structure):

- Read your line and use `string.split("\\s+");` to break your line into word tokens (`\\s+` denotes one or more space in regular expression language).
- If you can be certain that the word will always be the first element in the line, then, you can iterate from your 2nd token (your first number) till your last token (your last number) and with each iteration you create a new `Type` object where the `type` is the first token and the `number` is the `nth` token.

The above should allow you to construct objects which when printed, will yield your desired output.

If on the other hand, the order of the tokens is not known, but you are sure that in every line you will have one word and `n` numbers, you can use further regular expressions such as `^\\w+$` and `^\\d+$` to see which token is either a word or a digit respectively. Once you know which token is what, you can refer to the above points to get your code to work.

For more information on regular expressions, you can take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) tutorial.

Comment: yeah i know its solvable that way but i prefer using scanner, since it could be real useful in general when handeling files since it splits them to tokens implicity.